# Javascript web application does not show certificate not trusted in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an application using https to do a jsonp call on my server which is self signed.

If I use the corresponding url in the Chrome address bar, then a warning is showing with 'The site's security certificate is not trusted!'. There the user can proceed anyway.

Now in my web application, there is no such warning and the request just remains pending indefinitely. I can see that in Developer tools. I would expect having something showing on chrome similar to the above behavior.

Chrome version is currently 25.0.1364.172.

Is this normal?
What should I do to address this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is normal. Try to browse via firefox, backup the Certificate and install it in Chrome again.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try. Is this considered a bug? Would you have a pointer on some info from Google on this?

Comment: My test yesterday was not conclusive with firefox. It was actually worse than with Chrome. I will post a different question regarding the behavior with Firefox, or update my qyestion.